# How do I make WPF windows available in a class library?

Tags: c#, wpf, class-library

I'm creating a class library that makes available some XAML windows (in theory). To create the XAML, I right clicked on the project and then clicked Add->New Item, and then specified Window (WPF). I then created my XAML, which I had already prototyped in a stand alone application. However, when I go to build my project, I get the following error:

```
The type name 'MyWindow' does not exist in the type 'MyProjectName.MyProjectName'
```

The header of my XAML looks like the following:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProjectName.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MyWindow" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Height="300" Width="300">
```

Unfortunately, it says the error is occurring on line 4 column 25, which ends up being the following unhelpful snippet `w" WindowStyle=` in the XAML.

The build action for the XAML is `Page`. What does this error mean and how can I fix it so my windows are available in the class library?

Comment: Do you have a code behind file? If so what is the namespace and does it inherit from a base class?

Comment: The code behind file is of the namespace MyProjectName. The class definition in the code behind is: public partial class MyWindow : Window

Comment: I ran into a really weird situation with a third party dll when I tried to use a namespace that had one similar part to their namespace. The compiler was confused and I eventually had to change my namespace. My namespace was "A.B.C" and theirs was "X.B". Probably a long shot... That's why I'm not confident enough to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a class with the same name as its namespace, which you can do with code-only, but not with XAML-only or XAML+code.

Change the class name or the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing that pops to mind. Are you sure you added a project reference from your WPF executable to the library?

Comment: The errors occur when I am building the class library, so not sure why adding references to the library that doesn't build would solve the problem.